# jQuery auto-complete altered to work with jQuery-Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I have code written to autocomplete a text input box from a mysql database. I am currently in the process of mitigating the setup to jQuery Mobile but I am having substantial issues finding out how to write a modified autocomplete. My original html is below (heavily simplified)

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head> 
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#get_ingredient_1" ).autocomplete({source: 'search.php'});
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="get_ingredient_1" name="ingredient_type" style = "width:200px">
</div>
</html>
```

the search.php is shown below.

```
<?php
//database configuration

include("db_connect.php");  

//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

//get matched data from skills table
$category_query = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT DISTINCT ingredient FROM ingredients WHERE ingredient LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY ingredient ASC"); 
//while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($category_query)){  
    $data[] = $row['ingredient'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

this outputs in the format:
["Adzuki beans","Alfalfa","Allspice","Almond meal"]

ive tried to comment it accordingly. Essentially this generates a text input bot and when you start typing will try and guess what ingredient you are wanting.

unfortunatly when I alter the jquery files to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

It no longer autocompletes. Ive read through dozens of examples but I cant find a basic 1 input autocomplete option that I can adapt.

Can anyone shed some light on how to alter this short piece of code to autocomplete, so I can study and adapt it to its full functionality.

Ive looked at all the jquery-mobile examples but have found them lacking in the details I need here, specifically the "remote listview" as it has to populate from a file generated from a mysql source like the search.php shown above.

hope someone can help translate this to jquery mobile use.

Comment: Load jquery-ui before jQM in head. It's better to have a custom built library that includes autocomplete widget, hence avoid any conflict between ui and jQM.